# Redux createStore substitution needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using Redux and needed to use `createStore` declaration but it is deprecated. I need help to find an other way of solving my needs.

store.js

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const reducer = combineReducers({});
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState, 
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store.js'
import './bootstrap.min.css'
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

React.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: It was deprecated in favor of redux-toolkit. Would it suit you need? https://redux-toolkit.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

The [`createStore`](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) has been marked as deprecated, use [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and write modern Redux. [`configureStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) is the replacement and it has a much simpler API.

1. Install Redux-Toolkit as a project dependency.

   `npm install @reduxjs/toolkit`

   If you need the React bindings, ensure you have a current version of React-Redux installed as well.

   `npm install react-redux@latest`
2. Swap `createStore` for `configureStore`. Redux-Toolkit ships with the Redux-Devtools enabled by default, and it also includes the Thunk middleware by default.

   Previous:

   ```js
   import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
   import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
   import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
   ... imported reducer functions ...

   const reducer = combineReducers({
     ... imported reducer functions ...
   });
   const initialState = {/* any persisted/initial state */};
   const middleware = [thunk];

   const store = createStore(
     reducer,
     initialState,
     composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
   );

   export default store;
   ```

   New:

   ```js
   import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
   import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
   ... imported reducer functions ...

   const reducer = combineReducers({
     ... imported reducer functions ...
   });
   const preloadedState = {/* any persisted/initial state */};

   const store = configureStore({
     reducer,
     preloadedState,
   });

   export default store;
   ```

For a more in-depth review see the [Migrating to Modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/usage/migrating-to-modern-redux) guide.